# Rstudio data table subset using value

Tags: filter, data.table, subset, data-wrangling

Given the following data table and the following value:

```
ReportingDate <- as.Date("2022-12-31")

DT <- data.table(
  Date = as.Date(c("2020-01-01","2022-02-15","2023-01-15")), 
  TransactionAmount = c(120, 120, 240) 
)
```

How is possible to filter in this kind of way? The goal is to have only first two records that are minor than the reportingdate.

```
DT2 <- DT[Date < ReportingDate ,]
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? For me it returns two rows, both before `"2022-12-31"`.

Comment: indeed, the example works, my actual case was indeed a bit different with a different issue. Thanks!

Comment: Not only is it difficult to help when the sample data provided does not evidence the problem, you have not even described what exactly is wrong.